# how to uninstall eclipse (installed using .tar.gz)

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, synaptic

I installed eclipse using the .tar.gz file here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

However, I could not find it in synaptic package manager and when I ran apt-get remove eclipse, it said that the package was not installed

How do I uninstall it?

Comment: What did you do with that tar file?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854359/how-to-uninstall-eclipse. A .tar.gz is not a *package*; it's just a bunch of compressed files. Apt (including apt-get and Synaptic) handles only .deb packages, has never heard of .tar.gz, and cannot handle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get remove eclipse` will not work in this case because you have not installed it through the `apt` package manager

This is not the best solution but one thing you can do, Simply delete the `installation directory`

I am assuming you have installed Eclipse in your `home` directory. (By default it does so, as you can see in the image)

[image: img_Eclipse]

If not, simply go to that directory then run the following commands to delete the `eclipse` and `eclipse-workspace` folder

```
sudo rm -rf ~/eclipse

sudo rm -rf ~/eclipse-workspace
```

If you created the Desktop shortcut, then delete it separately